Логи telegram bot python loguru
Написал тг бота(на telebot), добавил логирование, используя библиотеку loguru, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что логирует только время, лвл и сообщение, а нужно чтобы было видно никнейм пользователя, отправившее это сообщение
Код бота:
from loguru import logger
import telebot
from telebot import types, TeleBot

bot: TeleBot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

logger.add('log/logs.log', level='DEBUG', format='{time} | {level} | {message}')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help_func(message):
    logger.debug('использовал /help')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Команды, доступные в боте:\n/start - открытие стартового меню бота')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    logger.debug('использовал /start')
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Курс валют')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(' Профиль')
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton(' Связь с разработчиком')
    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, выбери действие'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == ' Курс валют':
            logger.debug('использовал  Курс валют')
            curs = '<b>Курс валют</b>\n $ ~92 руб.\n€ ~98 руб.\n₸ ~0,2\n¥ ~12,5 руб.'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, curs, 'HTML')
        elif message.text == ' Связь с разработчиком':
            logger.debug('использовал  Связь с разработчиком')
            soc = '<b>Социальные сети</b>\n<b>VK</b>: https://vk.com/hzchotytpisat1\n<b>Discord</b>: energ0zzz1'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, soc, parse_mode='HTML')
        elif message.text == ' Профиль':
            logger.debug('использовал  Профиль')
            mess = f'<b>Профиль</b>\n<b>Имя</b>: {message.from_user.full_name}\n'
            mess2 = f'<b>Имя пользователя</b>: {message.from_user.username}\n'
            mess3 = f'<b>ID</b>: {message.from_user.id}'
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess + mess2 + mess3, parse_mode='HTML')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Сам лог:
2024-05-20T18:51:48.925226+0300 | DEBUG | использовал /help
2024-05-20T18:54:22.760029+0300 | DEBUG | использовал  Профиль
2024-05-20T18:54:23.375520+0300 | DEBUG | использовал  Курс валют
2024-05-20T18:54:23.376524+0300 | DEBUG | использовал  Связь с разработчиком

Повторяю, нужно чтобы в логах был НИКНЕЙМ или ID человека, который сделал действие в боте

Что в логи отправляете - то он и записывает. Меняйте logger.debug('использовал /help') на logger.debug(f'{message.from_user.id} использовал /help')'и т.д.
